# Cannot Give Myself Admin Access to folder in Local AppData on Win10

Tags: windows-10, file-permissions, administrator

I have a collection of files in my Local AppData folder from an install that failed. It seems I need to delete them manually, but I am unable to do so. I am an Admin on the PC and am logged in as such.

**Edited to explain solutions tried.**

I have tried the following solutions to no avail:

https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-take-ownership-and-get-full-access-to-files-and-folders-in-windows-10/

If I try this I only see dialogues like the following in the security tab:

[image: No Permission Message]

I also tried the takeown command:

[How would I use Takeown to take ownership of all folders on one drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/813878/how-would-i-use-takeown-to-take-ownership-of-all-folders-on-one-drive)

However, this command replies with "Access Denied" if tried from a cmd prompt with elevated privileges.

What else can I try?

Comment: Just because you are an Administrator on your machine doesn't mean you have access to the file.  If you want access to the file claim ownership of the file..  Have you done that?  Your screenshot says otherwise.  Update your question, once you have done that, and then clarify what you are still confused about.  "All of the help in the internet shows you how to give yourself ownership of a folder, but this is obviously not possible." - It actually is because you are an Administrator which means you can take ownership of any file on your machine.

Comment: @Ramhound - If I try to follow instructions such as these: http://windowsreport.com/take-ownership-windows-10/ I only ever see the dialog that says "You do not have permissions" when opening the "Change" link where it says "Unable to display current owner". I never see a list of owners with the option to change.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer with the help of this response to a related question:
https://superuser.com/a/162965/482319

I installed the Unlocker tool given in the link from that answer: [Unlocker](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/Unlocker.shtml). I opened the tool, browsed to the directory I wished to "unlock". The tool said that nothing had it locked, so I told it to delete the folder. Unlocker failed to delete the folder immediately, so I selected to "Delete on next restart" and restarted the PC. This option worked to remove specific folders.