# System Volume Infomation Full

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

I'm trying to remove the these files from the F:/ drive (see link) as they're preventing shadow copies from being created which is destroying our backup job.

I've tried rmdir "system volume information"/s /q and del /f (See Link)

Also tried to remove with Robocopy

Also tried to enable shadow copies but it's throwing back errors due to drive space.

Anyone know of a command or another way about deleting these?

Seems to think the files are not recognised or exist.

Server is 2008 r2

Any help would be very much appreciated

[TreeSize of F:/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/es5ck.png)

[Attempt at deleting AAlog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcoQv.png)

Comment: My issue was related to ownership https://superuser.com/questions/1338064/how-to-change-ownership-of-a-file-in-windows-10

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended directly delete the folder.

It store their files in this folder below:
System restore points on client systems or System State backups made using Windows Server Backup (wbadmin) in server OSs;
The contents of Indexing Service database used for fast file search;
Distributed Link Tracking Service database;
Disk snapshots made by Volume Shadow Copy, which can be used to recover older versions of files;
NTFS disk quota settings;
The database of file deduplication service;
DFS Replication database (dfsr.db).

Check the contents of folder
Run command :vssadmin list shadowstorage

Use the command below to delete the old shadow copy
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/vssadmin-delete-shadows