# Merging Data in Working Windows 10 With Corrupted Windows 10 (Dual Boot)

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning, multi-boot, data-recovery

My windows files got corrupted in a way that have prevented me from recovering the system(my laptop came without any OS so it didn't have a built-in recovery option for me to save Windows).

To login to my computer I installed another Windows 10 to another partition but all of my data remains in the corrupted Windows partition. I realize I can at least browse through my data when I run `cmd` as administrator, but I think what I am trying to accomplish is merging partitions to get all the data to my working Windows partition.

I am really scared of merging the partitions because I fear not being able to turn on my PC afterwards (because of the corrupted Windows installation). And my PC doesn't have enough free space as all of it is used in these 2 partitions;

So if I merge and can't boot Windows again I will need to delete all the partition to free space which means I'll lose all my data.

Long story short, can someone write a concrete solution to my problem to get the data from corrupted Windows partition to working Windows partition safely? (also corrupted Windows partition has more space than working Windows partition, so I won't be able to move all the data if I can't merge partitions.
Nevertheless even being able to copy some is a huge help.)

When I try to access from File Explorer, even when I am running it as admin, I can't access to my user's folder. I can from terminal, but if I can't merge partitions, then I need to visually filter what I want to pick to the new system.

While answering please keep in mind that I cannot login to the corrupted Windows (I tried startup repair and fix Windows from dual boot menu and it still didn't work).

Comment: It is also completely fine if somehow I can reverse the partitions if I can use working windows in my old partition. I just need to get my old files/files in the cache/logged in accounts etc back.I don't care about data in the new partition

Comment: Windows 10 was running. So if you can get your data (so you said above), put the data on a USB drive. Then reinstall Windows 10 (it will activate itself) and let Windows 10 build the partitions it needs (normally 3). That would be the simplest way and how I would do it.

Comment: reinstall which windows? I think what you are suggesting is, copy everything from corrupted pc's D storage to usb, then somehow wipeout data in corrupted version to install working windows there, am I right? And in that case does the "sudo" restriction in my old users Folder is still required? Because that is my main problem now, if I can reach that file from explorer, I can copy whatever I need

Comment: "reinstall which windows?"  <- Windows 10. Whatever Windows 10 version (Home, Pro, etc) was on the corrupted volume. That is after you recover your data. You need to do that as a fresh install will wipe out that data. It seems really complex to merge partitions. Just start fresh.

Comment: No I tried to clarify, I should just delete the contents of corrupted partition, right?(after storing data). And are you sure that this removes the lock in the user folder of corrupted windows? I am sorry if the questions are trivial, I read a lot but I am still a beginner

Comment: You will need to take ownership of the USER folder so you can get documents out of it. Your new install will make a new USER folder (and Account) but you will need to take ownership of that. You could not log into the original Windows (you said above) so you will need to take ownership of the USER folder. That will have to happen any way you proceed.

Comment: I see, so I assume what I need to do is to find the sudo chown -R equivalent in windows and assign D/users/corrupted user to myself. You can also write this as an answer, I will accept it and I can comment any further doubts in there

Comment: I did post a complete answer for you including a reference to take ownership of a folder. Keep all your files until you have successfully recovered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 10 was running. So if you can get your data (as you said above), put the data on a USB drive. Then reinstall Windows 10 (it will activate itself) and let Windows 10 build the partitions it needs (normally 3). That would be the simplest way and how I would do it.

The Windows you need is the version on the corrupted partition (Home, Pro, etc.)

Most data recovery is easy, but the documents in your USER folder are secured. You will need to take ownership of the USER folder so that you can recover documents from it. Your new, fresh install will build a new user folder (and Account). Once done, you can get the documents from the other user folder.

> I assume what I need to do is to find the sudo chown -R equivalent in
> windows and assign D/users/corrupted user to myself.

There is good information on taking ownership of a Windows 10 folder in this fairly recent SU Post.

[How to change ownership of a file in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1338064/how-to-change-ownership-of-a-file-in-windows-10)

Good luck.

Comment: Ok now the only "confusing" part is, when I installed this new Windows from USB, it did not let me build into the partition where my corrupted windows is occupying. So I am assuming there is an option to delete the partition when I am setting up the new windows?

Comment: You should be able to delete partitions as part of the install when you start with (boot with) the Windows 10 USB made from the Media Creation link:  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10